# How do I subdivide a cube?

Tags: edit-mode

Just installed 2.91 and I'm having a hard time finding some really basic questions answered.
Subdividing Primitives.
If I create a cube primitive how do I make it have 3 subdivisions on the X, 5 subdivisions on the Y, and 300 subdivisions on the Z.  Other programs have a dial or something.  I can't find it.

How do I make a primitive sphere with 41 subdivisions.  How can I see how many times the sphere is subdivided and change it when I change my mind.  I can see the number of faces but then I have to think.  I want to be able to ...again...dial a specific mesh density before it's editable.  Is that possible?

How do I select a ring of faces?  I found the grow and shrink selection but for the life of me...

I spent all yesterday doing tutorials and stuff but I'm brand spanking new.  And I think my questions are so basic that they don't get covered as much.  Or maybe I accidently deleted a toolbar.

Answer (score 9):

For subdividing a cube non-uniformly: your best bet is using the Loopcut Tool <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> in edit mode and then Scroll to add more segments). Some of blender's primitives don't have the options you want like other software does.

To add flat divisions uniformly: when in edit mode, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all components and then <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd>>Subdivide (**destructive operation**, can no longer edit after activating a different tool). As long as you don't perform any operations afterwards, you can expand the little properties panel in the bottom left to control how many subdivisions you want.

For non-destructive smooth subdivision levels:
<kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> for SubD level 1 <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> for SubD level 2, etc. Using this hotkey simply adds a [*subdivision surface modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html#subdivision-surface-modifier) and pressing different hotkeys for different levels simply changes the level of that exact same modifier. You can access this modifier from the Modifiers Panel on the right (little wrench).

For selecting ring of faces: Switch to Edit, then Face mode. <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> in between two faces to determine the direction of the loop. Add <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select more face rings or deselect existing ones.

Comment: This is the first time I've communicated with the Blender community.  And the effort put into answering my questions so thoroughly is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

When you create a cube you can't choose the amount of subdivisions right away, you need to switch to *Edit* mode and subdivide on all the axis (right click > *Subdivide*) or create an edge loop on an axis then scroll your wheel or set the number of edges in the *Operator* box:

[image]

When you create a UV sphere, though, you can choose the amount of subdivisions in the *Operator* box. Actually you can change the setup of a primitive as long as you don't move or edit it (<kbd>F9</kbd> is also a way to recall the primitive settings):

[image]

As for the *Edge Ring Select* operation, I guess it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> right click:

[image]